# storing dynamic form and data entered using json

Tags: jquery, json, forms, dynamic

im new to using JSON.. and i know this has probably already been asked here, however, i just want to consult if i'm doing the right thing.

I need to create a dynamic form for different pages. I need to be able to add a dynamic form for each page. From the admin panel, i can add/edit/delete fields in the page template -- change the order of the fields, name, type, values, etc.

So, what i did, i stored the dynamic form fields in json, and for the data entered in each page, i stored it in json as well. Below is a sample JSON data stored in my database:

**JSON structure for a dynamic form with 2 fields:**

```
{
"0":{
  "id":"511ddf15cb8ae_1", // generated using uniqid() and counter, to generate a unique id for each field
  "name":"Page Name #1",
  "type":"textfield",
  "validation":"email", 
  "require":"on",
  "value":""  //default value
},
"1":{
  "id":"511ddf15cb8ae_2",
  "name":"Field Name #2",
  "type":"checkbox",
  "validation":"none",
  "require":"on",
  "value":["item 1","item 2","item 3"]  //selection
}
}
```

**stored JSON of values entered:**

```
{
"511ddf15cb8ae_1":   //the field id, used as key to be able to directly access the data
  "test new data",
"511ddf15cb8ae_2":
  ["item 1","item 2"]
}
```

My main question is, is it ok if i store the entered values using json in the database, or should i store the entered values individually -- db table row.

Any ideas to do this in a better way, or is this fine already? Thanks.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you plan next:).

The approach you have taken is quite good, if you only plan to reconstruct the form later and populate with the entered value (I believe you are storing the dynamic form as well), in the sense that you don't need to re-construct the json back from entered value using complex queries.

But, it would be tedious if you later do some complex findings/queries on the values entered on respective field e.g 'How many times a particular user has entered a specific value in a specific field?' kind of. If you plan to do so then I would recommend go by relational approach and store them in tables; the dynamic form and the values entered.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your feedback, i appreciate it. Yes, i was thinking of the possible complex queries, that's why my first plan, was to store the fields individually in tables. But my concern also is, what if there are thousands of pages, then it might take up a lot of space in the database, since, yes, ill be storing the dynamic form too.. I think i'll stick to storing the whole json string in the table for now.

Answer (score 0):

Storing it as a string in a SQL database is OK, since you can always `stringify` and `parse` but I have found this extremely tedious, especially when I want to do JOIN operations or have complex structures represented persistently. Since you do have it in JSON already, why not use a NoSQL persistent storage mechanism like [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) and store the JSON itself.

[MongoDB allows you to save JSON documents in BSON format](http://www.mongodb.org), and then do queries on them, something your current implementation lacks.

In fact, you can open up the interactive MongoDB shell on their website, and prototype your database from there, using something like this:

```
> var page = {"name":"Page Name #1",   "type":"textfield",   "validation":"email",    "require":"on",   "value":"aValue"};
{
 "name" : "Page Name #1",
 "type" : "textfield",
 "validation" : "email",
 "require" : "on",
 "value" : "aValue"
 }
> db.pages.save(page);
"ok"
```

From there, once all pages are added you can now have robust queries, for instance this would find all the pages of type textfield:

```
db.pages.find({"type":"textfield"});
```

You could also do much more complicated and powerful queries with the values field, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your recommendation, it seems to be a really nice idea. But we're already using mysql database for our data storage.

Comment: You do risk some serious issues putting it in string form in a database, not least of which is true search, at least for compression, may I recommend [BSON](http://bsonspec.org) to save on space

Comment: Im using codeigniter by the way, does it make a difference? Or is it just bad practice to store json string in a database? Thanks.

Comment: If it works for you it's not bad practice, it's just that the point of a relational database is to have normalized data that is indexable so as to be easily query able, the way your using it is the same as if you were just reading and writing the JSON files to disk so your not taking advantage of the full power of your tools.